# Hibernate, how to do a many-to-one mapping on a may-be-unique column, ignoring duplication

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have 2 Hibernate entities:

```
@Entity
class Car {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_code")
    private BrandReference brand;
}


@Entity
class BrandReference {
    @Column(name = "brand_code")
    private String brandCode;
}
```

The table `BrandReference` will have data like this:

```
row_id | brand_code | brand_name
--------------------------------
   1   |  TOYO      | Toyota
   2   |  BENZ      | Mercedes-Benz
   3   |  HOND      | Honda
```

The column `brand_code` actually is expected to be unique. But I am in a situation where this expectation cannot be controlled. The data in table `BrandReference` is controlled by external party and it is unavoidable to have an error that cause the table to have more than 1 rows with the same `brand_code`

```
row_id | brand_code | brand_name
--------------------------------
   1   |  TOYO      | Toyota
   2   |  BENZ      | Mercedes-Benz
   3   |  HOND      | Honda
   4   |  HOND      | Gonda (Typo)
```

I don't like the program to crash on this situation. Is there a way to tell Hibernate to choose the row with the least `row_id` in case it found more than 1 rows with the matched `brand_code` when assigning a `BrandReference` to a `Car`. Something like this.

```
@Entity
class Car {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "brand_code")
    @GetFirstRow(orderBy = "row_id")
    private BrandReference brand;
}
```

Comment: Use select query  group by brand_code and order by row id limit 1.